# incomparable types boolean and nulltype

Tags: java, comparison

When I compile my code this way, I get the mentioned error:

```
public class SymTree{
public static boolean isSym(BT bt)
    {
        return(IsMirror(bt.left, bt.right));
    }
private static boolean IsMirror(BT lr,BT rr)
   {
       if(lr==rr==null)   (((ERROR HERE)))
        return true;
.....
```

However when I compile like this

```
    private static boolean IsMirror(BT lr,BT rr)
   {
       if(lr==rr)&&(lr==null))
        return true;
.......
```

I get no error. The error is uncomparable types with nulltype and boolean, however non of my compared objects are boolean- they are both objects from a BT(Binary Tree) class, which has been defined elsewhere.
Thank you!

Comment: the second form is way better to read IMO

Comment: The second form still won't compile - you want `if (lr == rr && lr == null)` or - better IMO - `if (lr == null && rr == null)`. It's not clear why you think the first form *should* compile. What do you believe the type of the expression `lr == rr` is, and how should that compare with `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's giving you that error is because when you write this:

```
if (lr==rr==null)
```

The compiler interprets it similar to one of the following:

```
if ((lr==rr) == null)

if (lr == (rr==null))
```

Basically, you're comparing a boolean condition (either `lr==rr` or `rr==null`) to a nullable type, which doesn't make sense since booleans are value types and can *never* be null.

Comment: @tamir No problem. If your question has been answered, make sure to mark whichever answer helped you the most.

Answer (score 2):

Examine `(lr==rr==null)`. `lr==rr` is a `boolean`. It is primitive and can not be compared to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because in `if(lr==rr==null)`, `lr==rr` is a boolean comparison which you are comparing with a `null` by doing `==null`.

For Example, if suppose `lr` is equal to `rr` then `lr==rr` will return `true` next you are comparing whether `true==null`. Here you get error because boolean and null are not comparable.